# Variable is not defined (sending from HTML to JS file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm trying to send a variable (`user.id` - current user's `id`) into my `JQuery` file which calls a view to delete some data in a database. The problem is that I don't know how to pass `user.id` into the JS file to be able to append it to `url` request.

In my template:

```
<script src="{% static "js/checkTestsSittings.js" %}">var userid = {{ user.id | safe }};</script>
```

JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(userid); // just a test
    request_url = '/check-sittings/'+userid+'/';
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url
    })
});
```

This is what I see in the console:

[image]

I'm beginner in JS and Django. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add file and code in a single script tag, you should add them independently, like this

```
<script>var userid = {{ user.id | safe }};</script>
<script src="{% static "js/checkTestsSittings.js" %}"></script>
```